# How to make a REST call to get list items from different sites using TypeScript, something like Promises?

Tags: typescript, rest, asynchronous, spfx

I am trying to retrieve list items from 2 different sites and do some action only once all data are retrieved. I thought of using something like .then() and Promises.

I am using SharePoint Framework, this is for Modern SharePoint extension, not a webpart.
I tried using [batching](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Batching) but it only applies to a single SharePoint site.

Thanks everyone for your help!!

William

```
let web = new Web("https://test.sharepoint.com/test2");
let batch = web.createBatch();

web.lists.inBatch(batch).usingCaching().get().then((r: any) => {
});

web.lists.getByTitle("SharePoint Directory").items.usingCaching().inBatch(batch).top(5000).get().then((r: any) => {
});

batch.execute().then(() => {
  console.log("Data retrieved.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script to call rest api to acess other site.(hard code the site url, you may build dynamically, the user need permission for other site also)

```
this.context.spHttpClient.get(`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList2')/items`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
      'odata-version': ''
      }
      })
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((data)=>{
          console.log(data);
        })

      });
```

Comment: Hello Lee,

Thanks for your reply, are you suggesting to use something like this? https://mmsharepoint.wordpress.com/2018/06/08/use-sharepoint-rest-api-batch-component-to-retrieve-site-logos/

Comment: Ideally, you could use the search api, but it depends on your requirement as search will not refresh data immediately as it depends on online search crawl. Graph might be better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0(the code would be complex than rest api request)